# C++ C2100 Illegal Indirection on initialize struct variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm using "VS2017 Community", platform Windows 7. And I got an error C2100 when tried to do next:

```
struct Conf {
    unsigned int id;
    int test1;
    int test2;
    int test3;
    int test4;
    int test5;
    int test6;
};

Conf cf({
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
}); //<-- Here is error - C2100 Illegal Indirection
```

Can anyone tell me what is possible the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. Can you please post the exact complete error message ? Trying to understand which variable compiler thinks a pointer.

Comment: Your code works with both [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2E6S1kMAd7bNPMPO) and [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZWKc4TJDY3u5tLo2). So I think it's a VS problem.

Comment: It's neither; it's a C++ syntax issue with the parenthesis. Simply need to remove them, or add a constructor that takes in each variable as a table value.
Check the answers below, they compile no problem with the correct init values. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This struct has no constructor. The code you want is the following:

```
struct Conf {
    unsigned int id;
    int test1;
    int test2;
    int test3;
    int test4;
    int test5;
    int test6;
};

Conf cf = {
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
}; // Array initializer for struct type.
```

Comment: Data-race on our answers. :-)

Comment: And after I spent that time running tests of the code in my editor! :D
Good answers, too; whichever is marked is fine with me, so long as one is marked I'm happy!

Comment: Doesn't matter to me. I just reached 10,000, which was supposed to confer some kind of status or privilege, but I'll be darned if I can see what it is.

Comment: Probably just makes people fear your presence; you words have weight now as opposed to a starter-out! You're basically an admin now. ;)

Comment: "This struct has no constructor." - can you elaborate?

Comment: Of course, @codekaizer.
The code written by the query bloke, is attempting to index a function call.

I.E. He's trying to initialize the array by using it as a parameter for a non-existant constructor.

Conf cf ({}); 
Basically, this will throw an error since the struct has no definition for initializing using these parenthasis. So they need to simply use
Conf cf = {};
Or, they could create a constructor in their struct that takes in the array and assigns them that way. :)

Comment: true. so my point is, there's still an implicitly defined constructor but it doesn't match `({})`

Comment: @codekaizer The implicitly defined copy constructor should match it.

Comment: @songyuanyao, thanks for mentioning the **copy** constructor should match it.

Comment: @codekaizer The `{...}` part could be used to construct a temporary `Conf`, then the temporary could be used to copy construct `cf`. That's why I think the code should be valid.

Comment: @songyuanyao, i see. so there's a list initialization first that's happening due to `{..}` and then the temp `Conf` object is passed to a copy ctor. Am I right? I believe this is valid and concur with your comment to OP.

Comment: @songyuanyao or could this be a most vexing parse where `Conf cf({});` is declared as a function and the parameter is a temp `Conf` object?

Comment: @codekaizer Yes. More precisely when constructing the temporary aggregate initialization is performed. And no, no most vexing parse here.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the round brackets. The compiler is trying to use a constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
struct Conf {
    unsigned int id;
    int test1;
    int test2;
    int test3;
    int test4;
    int test5;
    int test6;
};

Conf cf {  // Curlies only
    1u,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    7
}; 

int main() {
    std::cout << cf.id << " " << cf.test6 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "The compiler is trying to use a constructor", can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is [**Most vexing parse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) where

`Conf cf({..});` is understood as a function with a temp `Conf` object as a parameter.

The temp `Conf` object is list-initialized as seen below.

From [`dcl.init#17.1`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#17.1):

> If the initializer is a (**non-parenthesized**) braced-init-list or is =
>   braced-init-list, the object or reference is *list-initialized*.

```
struct S2 {
  int m1;
  double m2, m3;
};
S2 s21 = { 1, 2, 3.0 }; // OK
S2 s22 { 1.0, 2, 3 };   // error: narrowing
```

So just list-initialize `cf` directly:

```
Conf cf {...};
```

Comment: The compiler will choose a function declaration over a variable definition if it can, but I don't see how it could interpret `{...}` as the function declaration parameters